# Adding a percentage (%) to a price with PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am wanting to know how to show a 3% surcharge in one column then add that to the total price

I have a variable set up $percent = '0.03'; which is 3% right?

Then have this in my total col - printf("%.2f", $invoice['invoice_amount'] + $percent); but it's only adding 3pence and the actual total in this case with the 3% surcharge would be £190.55 according to Google!

How can I just show what percentage is been added to in this case would be 5.55

Please help me, I'm going round in circles!

Answer (score 2):

```
$p=$invoice['invoice_amount'] * $percent;
printf("%.2f", $invoice['invoice_amount'] + $p);
```

Comment: How can i just show what percentage is been added to in this case would be 5.55 in the percentage column i have?

Comment: not sure what you are asking, but if you want just to show the percent value instead of adding it try: echo($invoice['invoice_amount'].' + '.$p); or something like this.

Comment: So i can show this:
SubTotal £180.00
Surcharge: £5.55 - This is what i want to show
Total: £190.55

Answer (score 2):

Add $percent back into the invoice amount
Try something like

```
printf("%.2f", $invoice['invoice_amount'] + ($invoice['invoice_amount'] * $percent));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to multiply the invoice amount by the percent and then add that result back to the original invoice amount.